# jquery ui autocomplete performance

Tags: jquery, performance, autocomplete

I have a page that at could have a large number numbers of controls attached with autocomplete. (over 70) I am finding that my page tends to slow down and IE would even show the warning to stop the script. 
I have also found the browswer memory using starts to increase with every postback - it can end up to almost 300MB after which IE really slows down or stops responding.

Has anyone had a similar experience to the above when using a large number of autocomplete controls please?
Is there a way to improve the performance of this?

Thanks,

Joseph

Comment: Why do you need so many autocomplete controls? Are you **really** need it?

Comment: All requests return results from the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied 2 fixes that greatly improved performance.

1. The code in jquery ui that adds a combo box has negative performance impact. I have now added the combo through standard html.
2. I have modified my code, so that autocomplete controls are instantiated on first focus rather than on page load.